# ConfigurationManager.GetSection returns null

Tags: c#, app-config

Here is my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
      <section name="procedureList" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.30319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </configSections>

  <procedureList>
    <add key="NAS.spBusObjGetLineProd" value="@area='Melt Shop';@endDt=?date?;@dayonly=1;@obj='Melt Shop Business Objective" />
    <add key="NAS.spBusObjGetLineProd" value="@area='Cold Mill';@endDt=?date?;@dayonly=1;@obj='Cold Mill Business Objective" /> 
  </procedureList>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Connstr" value=""/>
    <add key="Userid" value=""/>
    <add key="Timeout" value=""/>
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

But when I call it in code, I'm getting a null back

```
public void samplemethod()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("procedureList") as NameValueCollection;
    string[] keys = nvc.AllKeys;
}
```

I would appreciate any help pointing out what I've done wrong

Comment: you're casting it incorrectly.I will post an example below along with a link you can use as a reference

Comment: If the `as` cast operation fails, it returns a null value.  However, configuration file notes that the section type is `NameValueSectionHandler` -- you should be casting to this type when calling GetSection().

Comment: even when I change the type to NameValueSectionHandler, I'm still getting a null back

Comment: what is the value of nvc when you place a break point..?

Comment: just to see what would happen, I just returned an object, like below but still got a null.
    object nvc = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("procedureList");

Comment: Yes that cast was causing me errors. Instead of `type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.30319, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"` 

I used `type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Using section handlers to group settings in the configuration file](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10981/Understanding-Section-Handlers-App-config-File)

For example you can follow something like the following

```
private void ReadSettings()
{
    NameValueCollection loc = 
   (NameValueCollection )ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig("procedureList");
}
```

[MSDN ConfigurationManager.GetConfig Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: got it figured out.  I had the app config in the dll, not the calling form.  since ultimately the dll is going to be called by a service, I need to fix that with ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration.  Thanks for the prodding.

Comment: Not a problem.. that's why I always ask developers if they debug their code.. it's an awesome tool the Debugger... glad you got it working

Comment: Have you tried: `NameValueCollection nvc = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("procedureList");` ? I suggest this, because `ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig` is **obsolete** now :/

Comment: Okay wait, just local errors. It will go dead some day.  Essential data would be better locally.

Comment: I gave an example that works not sure why you down voted it but it's all good.. cheers

Comment: @edepperson Could you please elaborate on how you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 6):

If you are testing your class you must copy the configuration to the `app.config` in your Test project.

Answer (score 1):

using immediate window check which config file it is pointing to. in my case i had app.config which i am expecting it to read, but on using the command. ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None) it is pointing to something else like nuintrunner.exe.config as that info is loaded into bin. this help in loading the right configuration file